# Add/Remove items from an array when cells are selected/deselected

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a very simple calendar (using Ionic/AngularJS) which uses a fictional month, it is a just a table that contains the numbers 1-31.

I have it currently working so that when a user presses the cell a class of 'selected' is added to the selected 'td' and the contents of the 'td' are added to an array.

This appears to be working great, however, if I was to deselect a cell then the item is once again added to the array of 'answers' so now I have duplicates in my array.

How can I modify my code in the following fiddle to select/deselect fields and amend my 'answers' array accordingly?

**MyCtrl**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];

  $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
        var elem = event;

        if(elem.target.className == 'selected')
            elem.target.className = '';
        else
            elem.target.className = 'selected';

        $scope.input.answers.push(parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML));
        console.log($scope.input.answers);
    }
}
```

**Template (HTML)**

```
<div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table class="calendar">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>M</th>
                        <th>T</th>
                        <th>W</th>
                        <th>T</th>
                        <th>F</th>
                        <th>S</th>
                        <th>S</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-click="bindCellValue($event)">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>24</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                        <td>26</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>29</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>31</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8sxj6df/

Comment: The JSFiddle doesnt match the code you posted here. Did you update it ?

Comment: Good spot, sorry, I actually forgot to fork the fiddle I was using as a template. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to check the array before pushing. If the element exists, just remove that from array, if needed. This is how the updated Controller will look.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];

  $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
        var elem = event;

        if(elem.target.className == 'selected')
            elem.target.className = '';
        else
            elem.target.className = 'selected';
        num = parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML);
        if($scope.input.answers.indexOf(num) == -1){
            $scope.input.answers.push(num);
        }else{
            $scope.input.answers.splice($scope.input.answers.indexOf(num),1);
        }

        console.log($scope.input.answers);
    }
}
```

To see it working live, check the forked JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/zqbL8nc0/

Let me know if you have any doubts / questions.

Comment: As you got in first and works you get the correct answer! Thank you very much, I think I was actually over thinking this a little and now I see your answer it makes sense and Im kicking myself a little right now... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splice function when deselecting the date.

Update JS code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];

  $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
        var elem = event;

        if(elem.target.className == 'selected'){
            elem.target.className = '';            
            var elemIdx = $scope.input.answers.indexOf(parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML));
            $scope.input.answers.splice(elemIdx, 1);            
        }
        else{
            elem.target.className = 'selected';
            $scope.input.answers.push(parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML));
        }

        console.log($scope.input.answers);
    }
}
```

See working code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whj4z346/

Answer (score 0):

Try this pop the selected element

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];

  $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
        var elem = event;

        if(elem.target.className == 'selected'){
            elem.target.className = '';
            $scope.input.answers.pop(parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML));
        }
        else{
            elem.target.className = 'selected';

        $scope.input.answers.push(parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML));}
        console.log($scope.input.answers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check taht array already contains this item or not. If yes then remove it from array or if not then add it to array.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];
    $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
    var elem = event;

    if(elem.target.className == 'selected')
        elem.target.className = '';
    else
        elem.target.className = 'selected';
    var value = parseInt(elem.target.innerHTML);
    var index = $scope.input.answers.indexOf(value);
    if( index > -1 ){
        //remove element 
        $scope.input.answers.splice(index, 1);
    }else{
        // add element   
        $scope.input.answers.push(value);
    }

    console.log($scope.input.answers);
}
}
```

Please refer to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2wodh1p/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.input = [];
    $scope.input.answers = [];

  $scope.bindCellValue = function(event) {
        var elem.target = event;

        if(!elem.className.match(/selected/)){
            elem.classList.add("selected");
            $scope.input.answers.push(parseInt(elem.innerHTML));
        } else {
            elem.classList.remove("selected");
            var val = parseInt(elem.innerHTML),
                index = $scope.input.answers.indexOf(
                             parseInt(elem.innerHTML)
                        );
            if (index >= 0) {
                $scope.input.answers.splice( index, 1 );
            }
        }
        console.log($scope.input.answers);
    }
}
```

That should solve your problem. If it doesn't please let me know soon...